# How to pass parameters permanently javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How would I make this function work so that whenever the element I created is clicked it uses the parameters from the function in the actual click event.

```
 function createLink(text, parentElement) {
        var a = document.createElement('p');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        temp1 = text.replace("/","-");
        temp2 = res1.replace("/","-");
        a.onClick = goSpecificPrev(temp2,linkText);
        parentElement.appendChild(a);
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        parentElement.appendChild(br);
    }
```

The parameters in questions are in the line:

```
a.onClick = goSpecificPrev(temp2,linkText);
```

being temp2 and linkText.

Comment: Make your variable global.

Comment: The problem is that the variable will need to be reused in a for loop so that won't work! Any other suggestions?

Comment: `return a.onClick;`, then create another function to take the rest code